# Передача методов через postmessage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Дан страничка и фрейм
На страничке есть кнопка которая отправляет некий конфиг фрейму

```
let upConfig = {
    getName: function ():any {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve('HI im promise');
        })
      }
    };
    const frame = this.frame.nativeElement.contentWindow;
    upConfig.getName = upConfig.getName.toString() as any;
    upConfig = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(upConfig));
    console.log(upConfig)
    frame.postMessage(upConfig, 'http://localhost:4201');
```

Пробема заключается в том, что фрейм получает методы в строковом режиме их нужно преобразовывать в реальные методы`

Comment: как говорит нам вики мозиллы, сообщение (первый параметр), передаваемое через [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), сериализуется с помощью [спец. алгоритма клонирования](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm), который позволяет безопасно передавать javascript-данные между разными источниками, не опасаясь, что кто-то передаст функцию, как это делаете Вы.

Answer (score 0):

Все, нашел

```
const f = new Function(someString)();
  alert(f);
```

где someString какая-то функция, к примеру

```
someString = 'let a = 2; a*=4; return a;';
```